# GIT svn how to update a path

Tags: git, git-svn

When using svn, I update a repository with the following command.

TortoiseProc.exe /command:update /path:"c:\FoldToSVNRepository"
TortoiseProc.exe /command:update /path:"c:\FoldToSVNRepositoryTwo"
TortoiseProc.exe /command:update /path:"c:\FoldToSVNRepositoryThree"

How would you do the equivilant with the command
git svn ?

I've had a look through the documentation but cannot find any way to specify the repository directory to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git --git-dir=C:\repo\.git svn fetch
```

Comment: Thank you, I was using hte --git-dir incorrectly then. Thought you had to be on the base directory not the actual .git directory.